DSBulk count returns more rows than unloaded in CSV files
I'm doing dsbulk unload for one table, with one primary key field, without clustering key.
At the end in console I see something like this
      total | failed |    rows/s |  p50ms |  p99ms | p999ms
174,971,236 |      0 | 1,946,689 | 148.95 | 285.21 | 400.56

but when I counting number lines in all csv files I getting ~170M, in ~5M less.  My main confusing difference in cli output and number in csv files.
I also:
dsbulk count shows me same result as unload ~175M.
My general question why it happens? What is explanation? What real size of my table? and how to debug?
I already did dsbulk count with --dsbulk.engine.maxConcurrentQueries 1, --datastax-java-driver.basic.request.consistency LOCAL_QUORUM and number is same ~175M.

if you could update your question post re-running your DSBulk unload command with --dsbulk.log.verbosity 2 and upload the below items,

what version of C* cluster is this
the log file generated
full command executed and full console output (of course, if you want to redact any sensitive info, pls do so)
cat <your_excel_file> | wc -l

then we may analyze this further.

The discrepancy between dsbulk unload and dsbulk count you described indicates that the replicas in the cluster are inconsistent.
By default, DSBulk operations are executed with a consistency of LOCAL_ONE, giving preference to higher throughput over consistency. When you perform a count with LOCAL_QUORUM, the result you get will have a higher consistency but would be slower to execute.
You should perform repairs regularly to keep the replicas in the cluster synchronised. If you are consistently seeing dropped mutations (this is what leads to inconsistencies), consider increasing the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes.
As a workaround, you should also run unload with a higher consistency. Cheers!

Hello Erick,
sorry for my bad problem explanation.
main problem what confusing me is that unload output in cli - 174,971,236, but
cat * | wc -l in directory with csv files.
shows me 169,966,876
Does it expected in some cases?
